# How to bind data from Api to Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I've bulid a small app that get data from `http://open-notify.org/Open-Notify-API/ISS-Pass-Times/` and dispalys it in a table. Since i'm new to vue i don't understand why i can't set the data to the view. I've created a dummy component calls "cell" which looks like this :

```
Vue.component("cell", {
   template: '<ul>'
   +'<li v-for="foo of apiData">'
   +' {{foo}} '+
  '</li></ul>',
  props:['apiData']
 })
```

In the view i've called it like this :

```
 {{apiData|json}} // trying to get a preview of data
  <cell></cell> // calling component
```

And keep getting an empty object - i guess it's because the api call is taking a few seconds more than the markup is loaded....

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/7savgjfo/)

Comment: Where are you passing apiData to cell?

Comment: @Devon Thanks, it's being passed in the props of the component... props:['apiData']

Comment: No, that's where it's declared, where is it being passed?

Comment: If you define a property on cell, you still have to pass data to that component via that property.  I.E. `<cell :apiData="apiData"></cell>`

Comment: @Devon Thanks again, the problem is that i can't display the data from the api - i've set a varible called apiData - to store the response - but i keep getting an empty object... as i've said - i think it's caused by a delay of the request.....any ideas? thanks

Comment: Yeah, you've got quite a few problems in your code from a brief review.  You might want to narrow down your question, or narrow down your code, and work on one piece at a time.

Comment: @Devon Thanks, i'm not sure what to narrow down exactly since nothing except the cell component - is relevant to the problem.... sure would be nice if you'll give some tips. thanks,

Comment: You have a scope issue (your axios callback is a regular function). Here is your fiddle updated. https://jsfiddle.net/de31hv9w/4/

Comment: @Bert - Oh.... got it thanks!!!